# Published fork of repo to jitpack but can't access it through gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

A library I'm currently using has a crash in, and a user has fixed it but it seems like the author is inactive so it won't be merged. I took a fork of the library and pushed his fix to the fork.

The fork is https://github.com/Daniel-sims/android-signaturepad/releases/tag/1.3.2

I've released this to jitpack with this build log - https://jitpack.io/com/github/Daniel-sims/android-signaturepad/1.3.3/build.log

The project builds fine locally, but the logs show errors to with finding the binding adapter classes.

My config locally is

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

At my project level and

```
implementation 'com.github.Daniel-sims:android-signaturepad:1.3.3'
```

at my app level, this is the latest release tag but when syncing Gradle it still throws a warning;

`Failed to resolve: android-signaturepad-1.3.3`

If I change my implementation to

```
implementation 'com.github.Daniel-sims:android-signaturepad:1.3.3'
```

It recognises that 1.3.3 is the latest version with a highlight.

Would the issues in the log be causing this issue or is there anything else in the log as from what I can see the build was actually successful despite the errors.

Comment: The output does not list the actual artifact (AAR). It has the sources JAR and the POM, along with hashes. So, I suspect that your build errors are your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I'll take a look at getting the errors fixed. The project builds locally normally, but shows the errors if I build gradle manually.